# Learn zend, magento modules and magento API

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, module, api, zend-framework

I can already use magento and I have some php basics. Now I would like to deepen zend, magento modules and magento API. You could link me all the best resources to learn this?

Comment: Follow https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLzL6POQkgepUvdqkalKdcg/videos you will get some idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For Zend Framework

https://framework.zend.com/learn

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/

> For Magento 2 Developer Documentation

https://devdocs.magento.com

> For Magento 2 Video tutorial

https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/

> For Magento 2 Web API

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-start-with-magento-2-api/

> For Magento 1 Developer Documentation

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/

> For Magento 1.x REST API

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

> Magento 2 Other tutorial:

https://www.toptal.com/magento/magento-2-tutorial-building-a-complete-module

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/

> Magento 1 Other Tutorials

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento-1/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Good detailed answer. @Mastafis you should check the answer. Nice info

Comment: Thanks a lot Muhammas, very good answer. I forgot to write that I use magento 1, so if you have other links to learn they are welcome.
Thanks again

Comment: No Problem. I added 2 more Magento 1 tutorial in answer. I hope it's help. keep coding :) thanks :)